# scheduling Jmeter distributed testing

Tags: unit-testing, scheduling, distributed, jmeter

I am using JMeter's distributed testing feature which works fine. However, when I schedule this distributed run, it just runs immediately and disregards schedules.  It happens only for distributed testing.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across that little gem.  Have you tried [starting from the command line](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/remote-test.html) to see if it works properly?

```
Step 3b: Start the JMeter from a non-GUI Client

As an alternative, you can start the remote server(s) from a non-GUI (command-line) client. The command to do this is:

jmeter -n -t script.jmx -r
or
jmeter -n -t script.jmx -R server1,server2...

Other flags that may be useful:
-Gproperty=value - define a property in all the servers (may appear more than once)
-Z - Exit remote servers at the end of the test.


The first example will start whatever servers are defined in the JMeter property remote_hosts; the second example will define remote_hosts from the list of servers and then run the remote servers.
The command-line client will exit when all the remote servers have stopped.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. The issue was from my side where the slave machine's date time was not in sync with the master.  It now works.